# How can I customize the color of the tabbedPane at swing builder?

Tags: java, swingbuilder, swing-app-framework

I want to customize the color of my tabbedPane to fit at the theme of my gui, but I don't know how to do it. I've tried lots of code but still nothing happens.

Here's my gui...
[image]

thnx in advance ^_^

Comment: are you trying to adjust the color of the tab or the inner component background (JTextArea)?

Comment: actually that was my 2 major problem... the color of of my tab, and i want to lessen the opacity of my TextArea (i want it to be transparent) to show the image at the back(i attached the picture at the jLabel)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple UIManager setting you can make before you create the GUI but they will be for every JTabbedPane:
This will change the selected tab color.

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.RED);
```

I don't see a setting for the border but you can hide it like so:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Lastly you can change the background of the tab pane like this:

```
tab.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the JTabbedPane look and feel, set the `UIManager` settings as described in this post [Controlling Color in Java Tabbed Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120728/controlling-color-in-java-tabbed-pane)

Relevant code:

```
  UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor ",ColorUIResource.GREEN);
  UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected",ColorUIResource.GREEN);
  UIManager.put("TabbedPane.background",ColorUIResource.GREEN);
  UIManager.put("TabbedPane.shadow",ColorUIResource.GREEN);

  // now construct the tabbed pane
  tab=new JTabbedPane();
```